# JQL to search subtasks of not completed stories

Tags: jql

I am trying to create a custom search that lets me see the subtasks I touched of tasks that are still not done. I have the two queries sorted out:

```
q1 -> status changed by [username] after -7d

q2 -> status != Done
```

I tried

```
status changed by [username] after -7d and Parent in (status != "Done")
```

But it throws an error...

I dont know how to apply the search correctly. On pseudo sql, it would be

```
Select * from tasks where 
    ( editor=[username] AND
      parent_task = (select taskID from tasks where status != "DONE")
```

Any idea as on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your requirement cannot be achieved using native JQL.
You can use a plugin like [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/cloud/overview), in order to fulfill your requirement.